# React-native version miss match tried every solution available on stack-overflow and other platforms

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am trying to expo start in my project and running it on tunnel using IOS. I have tried searching for it, creating new project and tried everything I found on internet but nothing works.

[image]

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "test_proj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "32.0.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

App.json

```
{
  "name": "test_proj",
  "displayName": "test_proj",
  "expo": {
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sure that if you are using expo then you are going to be restricted in the version of `react-native` that you can use.

Comment: I don’t get it can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: your react-native field in package should be like this `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",`

Answer (score 2):

From the `Expo` [documentation](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v32-0-0-is-now-available-6b78f92a6c52)

> Expo SDK v32.0.0 is based once again on [React Native 0.57 “September 2018”](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.57.1), the same major version as SDK 31.

So as far as I am aware SDK 32 only works with react-native: 0.57.1 so trying other versions won't work.

In `Expo` projects the `react-native` dependency usually looks like this in the `package.json`

```
react-native: "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
```

So returning your `react-native` dependency to what it was originally may fix the issue.

---

An alternative reason for the mismatch error is that it can be caused by using the bundler with one version of `react-native` and then trying to use a different version without clearing the bundler.

To fix this error you can do it by:

1. Closing the bundler
2. Clearing the [cache](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d)
3. Restarting the bundler
4. Restarting the app

Comment: It was exactly the problem. I never thought react-native version was a dependency. Thank you

Comment: Unable to resolve "schedule/tracking" from "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js"
Now there is this issue If you could help please.

Comment: @SaifKhan I suggest that if you have a new question, you should ask a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) making sure you provide all the details to replicate it.

Comment: Now it's different error I'll post question when I am stuck on same issue I have trying different things. So yeah I'll post it when I have tried everything.